# Taylor's formula for a $C^{0,1}$ function: continuity of the remainder

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, taylor-expansion

Let $f \in C^{0,1}(\mathbb R^2)$, that is $f$ is continuous and the second partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x$ exists and is continuous. Then, by Taylor's formula,
\begin{equation*}
R(t,x,h) = \frac{f(t,x+h) - f(t,x)}{h} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x)
\end{equation*}
defines a function in $(t,x,h) \in \mathbb R^3$, such that, for all $(t,x) \in\mathbb R^2$, $R(t,x,\cdot)$ is a continuous function taking the value zero in zero.

If $f \in C^1(\mathbb R^2)$, then $R$ is continuous as a function $\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

**Question**. For general $f \in C^{0,1}(\mathbb R^2)$, is $R$ continuous as a function $\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$? If not, can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

**Counterexample**: $f(t,x) = \frac{2tx}{\sqrt{t^2+x^2}}$, the typical example of a componentwise differentiable, but not differentiable function does the job, since in that case,
\begin{equation*}
R(h,h,h) = \frac{8 - 3 \sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{20}} \neq 0
\end{equation*}
for $h > 0$.